# Why private members are not passed from Cadence activities?

Tags: go, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

I noticed that when I use a struct consisting of both public and private members, then the private ones are not copied(?) by Cadence activities.

For example I have a struct:

```
package foo

type Foo struct {
    Name        string
    PublicList  []string
    privateList []string
}

func NewFoo() *Foo {
    return &Foo{
        Name:        "Test",
        PublicList:  []string{"A", "B", "C"},
        privateList: []string{"one", "two"},
    }
}

func (f *Foo) ShowLists() {
    fmt.Println("PublicList: ", f.PublicList, ", privateList: ", f.privateList)
}
```

I also use other struct, registered as activities struct:

```
package activities 

type FooActivities struct{}

func (a *FooActivities) NewFoo(ctx context.Context) (*foo.Foo, error) {
    return foo.NewFoo(), nil
}

func (a *FooActivities) ShowLists(ctx context.Context, f *foo.Foo) error {
    f.ShowLists()
    return nil
}
```

My workflow calls these two activities in a following way:

```
var f *foo.Foo
workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, fooActivities.NewFoo).Get(ctx, &f)
workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, fooActivities.ShowLists, f).Get(ctx, nil)
```

The result, printed by `ShowLists` function:

> PublicList:  [A B C] , privateList:  []

Why is the private list not initialized as expected? Is this a bug or feature? I couldn't find answer for this question in the Cadence documentation.

Comment: As you said, these are private, or unexported fields which aren’t accessible from other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cadence (and Temporal) by default use `json.Marshal` to serialize and `json.Unmarshall` to deserialize activity arguments. It doesn't serialize private fields.

[Here is](https://riptutorial.com/go/example/14194/marshaling-structs-with-private-fields) a possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem! BTW I don't think that my question is a duplicate. It's about Cadence, not about JSON marshalling. Information about usage of json.Marshal in Cadence is part of the answer, not question. (@JimB, @blackgreen)

Comment: Next time don't put Go tag on a question :).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cause by reflect cann't copy unexported field